# How to add a AggregateDefinition to camel context at runtime

Tags: apache-camel

I have a route that uses aggregation strategy, because of that it produces a AggregateDefinition as opposed to RouteDefinition. The CamelContext provides API to add a RouteDefinition but not an AggregateDefinition.

How can I add an AggregateDefinition to the camel context dynamically at runtime ?

Thanks
Srikanth.

Answer (score 0):

You can load/update routes from xml files as shown here:
http://camel.apache.org/loading-routes-from-xml-files.html

Otherwise CamelContext has Java API to add/remove/update routes as well. For example you can use a RouteBuilder class and just add that to the camel context using the api.

Comment: yes the only method i could use on CamelContext is by adding a RouteBuilder it self. There are couple of issues with that, 1) I must configure it as a "prototype" bean because once added to camel context it cannot be added again due to a boolean flag. 2) I need to create a RouteBuilder class on the fly at runtime or create a subclass of my own RouteBuilder. Because the default implementation creates the route with a JMS selector which doesn't work for the runtime creation. The JMS selector is different for the RB that is being created at runtime.